# React redux store vs component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with an input element.  Onchange, I want to update the Redux store and local state, because I render {this.state.inputValue} in the component.

The reason I need for it to be in the Redux store, is that the user could hit save button (which is on a different component) at anytime.

I can't think of any other way to keep local state, and allow a 'Save' to access the data.  But it seems like this approach breaks the 'single source of truth' rule.  What is the right way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Are save button component and input component parent - child or altogether different components ?

Comment: In my case, siblings.   The input can bind its data to an object in the parent, which works.  But again, still feels like not a single source of truth.  But I don't honestly know.

Comment: You could use `context` if that helps. Although you can do the same thing with `props` on a parent component.

Comment: What does "Save" do? Does the input need to know the difference between what is currently "saved" and what the last thing entered was? Is there any reason you can't just derive whether it's modified, based on `this.state.input === props.value`, where `props.value` is derived from `state.savedValue` or however you want to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve the problem. The solution assumes that the `InputFormComponent` and the `ActionComponent` are within some `ParentComponent` or can easily be wrapped in one.

The `ParentComponent` is wrapped with `connect` and has access to redux store. The Parent's render on an abstract level looks like this (there could be any level of siblings or nesting):

```
//Parent Component
render() {
    return (
        <InputFormComponent
            data={this.{state|prop}.initialData}
            userClickedSave={this.state.userClickedSave}
            clickSavedAcknowledged={this.clickedSavedAcknowledged}
        />

        <ActionComponent
            onSaveClicked={this.onSaveClicked}
        />
    )
}
```

From the above code we can understand that the `ParentComponent` has a `userClickedSave` flag on its `state`. It has a method called `onSaveClicked` which when called from the `ActionComponent` will update `this.state.userClickedSave` to `true`.

Now lets see how `InputFormComponent` will behave to `userClickedSave` on its `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
//Input form component
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.userClickedSave && this.props.userClickedSave !== nextProps.userClickedSave) {
        nextProps.clickSavedAcknowledged(this.state.inputValue)
    }
}
```

The `InputFormComponent` will listen for `userClickedSave` changes and for correct scenario, it will call `clickSavedAcknowledged` with the current input value, which the `ParentComponent` can now save to the redux store:

```
//Parent component
clickSavedAcknowledged(inputValue) {
    this.props.saveInputValue(inputValue)

    this.setState({
        userClickedSave: false
    })
}

onSaveClicked() {
    this.setState({
        userClickedSave: true
    })
}
```

As you can see the `Parent` saves data to redux store and also reset `userClickedSave` back to `false`, so the process can repeat when the user click the save button.